# Animate text alignment using jquery

Tags: jquery

At the click of a button `$('#btn').click()`, I want a group of `span` elements be set with CSS text-align right (originally text-aligned left) and make it animated so that the text slides from left to right.

I tried with `.animate({ 'text-align': "left")` but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried with `.addClass('alignRight', 1000)` again and the text did change but there is no sliding effect. When I tried with `.addClass('floatRight', 1000)`, it has similar effect with `alighRight`.

```
.alignRight{ text-align : right;}
.floatRight(float: right;}
```

So how do I give a sliding effect from left to right? The markup is like

```
<div id="main" style="width: 300px;">
    <div class="item" style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="info">Strings</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="width: 100%;">
        <span class="info">Strings</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery can animate various CSS properties but not ALL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## HTML markup (no change)

```
<div id="main" style="width: 300px;">
    <div class="item">
        <span class="info">Strings</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <span class="info">Strings</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS markup

```
.info {
    display: block;   /* width works better on block level elements */
    text-align: right;
    width: 20%;       /* use something sensible as the default value */
    overflow: hidden; /* if you choose 0% for the above property then use this */
}
```

## jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".info").animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 1000);
});
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/d4qTA/6/)

PS: I'd rather use CSS position relative+absolute along with CSS overflow+left properties.