# How to use jquery .animate() to mock 'text-align:right'

Tags: jquery

I am building a very simple jquery menu. On hover, I have a menu on the right easing to the left margin of my menu container. This is easy, as the text is left aligned within said container.

However, I also have a menu on the left, and because the links (left justified) are of differing length, the best I can do is adjust the padding to ease the text a uniform amount between links. Therefore, long link text goes to the right edge of the container, buy short text only makes it about half way.

In reading about this, I have learned that you can not modify the text align property as it is non numeric. Is there any other way to do this?

I of course tried to go with:

```
$('#selector').css('text-align':'right')
```

but that made the text jump to the right instead of ease.

Is there any way to ensure all links ease to the rightmost margin of the container?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate text alignment using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173327/animate-text-alignment-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the element relative, and them animate left/right properties

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6cAYv/

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <a href="#">Hover here</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#parent').hover(function(){
    var a =  $(this).find('a').first();
    a.css('position', 'relative').animate({ left: $(this).width() - a.width() }); 
},function(){
     $(this).find('a').first().animate({ left:0 });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have done. Only the container is 160px wide, and a couple of links are 20+ chars, a few are 4, and a few are around 10. I know that I could individual code a hover event for each link, I was just hopinng there was an easier way.....

Comment: @mrwienerdog you don't need to code individually. Edited my answer to provide a fiddle. They will always be animated parent width minus element width.

Answer (score 4):

You can not animate text-align. You can only animate numeric values, but not states.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me if you know the width of the container and the width of the text, this should be possible, as psuedo code:

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="text">Some Text!</span>
</div>
$(#container).css('margin-left',(widthOf#Container - widthOf#Text) + 'px' );
```