# Bidirectional CSS Transition

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm implementing the collapsing sticky header from this article on [how to create an animated sticky header, with CSS3 and jQuery](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/how-to-create-an-animated-sticky-header-with-css3-and-jquery/).

The header is currently animating all CSS changes with the following line:

```css
transition: all 0.4s ease;
```

When the sticky header is applied the following css properties change:

```css
  font-size:   72px;    /* --> 24px;    */
  line-height: 108px;   /* --> 48px;    */
  height:      108px;   /* --> 48px;    */
  background:  #335C7D; /* --> #efc47D; */
  text-align:  center;  /* --> left;    */
  padding-left: auto;   /* --> 20px;    */
```

So transition all should gracefully move between the existing value and new value for each of those properties.

However, I'm noticing that when I scroll down, the text nicely animates smaller and to the left.  However, when I scroll up, the text seems to jump out of the middle instead of moving right when it loses the `text-align:left` property.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var belowTop = $(this).scrollTop() > 30;
  $('header').toggleClass('sticky', belowTop);
});
```

```css
/*reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  color: #fff;

  font-size: 72px;
  line-height: 108px;
  height: 108px;
  background: #335C7D;
  text-align: center;
}
header.sticky {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #efc47D;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header><h1>Sticky Header</h1></header>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pezV.jpg" alt="Big Image" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that all the properties being changed will be animated is incorrect.

Only *animatable* properties will be transitioned gracefully, and `text-align` is not animatable.

Here's a [complete list of animatable properties from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

Here's a simplified example that increases the animation time.  It's easy to see that the animation to left align the text never occurred in the first place.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var belowTop = $(this).scrollTop() > 30;
  $('header').toggleClass('sticky', belowTop);
});
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2s ease;

  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
header.sticky {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header><h1>Header</h1></header>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pezV.jpg" alt="Big Image" />
```

As a workaround to animating text-align, here are a couple stack overflow threads with solutions involving other animatable properties or jQuery.

- [CSS3 - animate text align left/center/right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22923524/1366033)
- [Is it possible to transition text-alignment using CSS3 only?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18235764/1366033)
- [Animate text alignment using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6173327/1366033)
- [How to use jquery .animate() to mock 'text-align:right'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9827365/1366033)