# transition animation to text align: center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the below; but the margin isn't nearly as approximate as `text-align:center;` is there anyway I could toggle `text-align: center;` to occur with a animation transition until it gets to the point of `text-align: center;` similar to that which is achieved with the below.

```
if ($(".resource-section").hasClass("resource-section--expanded")) {
     $(".resources__header h2").animate({"marginLeft": "40%"}, "slow");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173327/animate-text-alignment-using-jquery

Comment: No.. I would really not like to mimic text align property with jQuery but actually use it.

Comment: I don't think you can animate a text-align property, but it's pretty trivial to simulate it with width or left/right properties +  a transition. Also, margin can be really accurate b/c you can measure the length of your text, then subtract half of that from the value of margin-left:50%

Comment: nop, just because left to center to right can only be three (forgot justify). You need numbers, so it can be broken (calculated) in as many steps as needed in order to create a transition within a given time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a centering technique that allows you to horizontally center any element.

It can be animated using only CSS

```css
.test {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  left: 0%;
  animation: center 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes center {
  0%, 10% {
      transform: translateX(0%);
      left: 0%; 
  }
  90%, 100% {
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      left: 50%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="test">TEST</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could animate `center` align using `margin-left` like this

```js
var h1 = $('h1').width();
var parent = $('.container').width();
$('h1').animate({'margin-left':(parent/2-h1/2)}, 1500);
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood if you want to use the  `text-align:center` property something like this could be of help to you, **but the `text-align` property can't be animated**

```js
$(function(){


  $('.resources_header h2').click(function(){
  
        $(this).toggleClass('align-center');
  
  });


});
```

```css
.align-center{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="resources_header">
    
    <h2>HEADER</h2>
    
  </div>  
</div>
```

A problem with this is the animation so if what you want to achieve is to animate from left to center then why not:

```js
$(function(){

  $('.resources_header h2').click(function(){
    
    
    var windowHalfWidth = $(window).width()/2;
    $(this).css('position','absolute');
    
    var elemHalfWidth = $(this).width()/2;           
    var left = windowHalfWidth - elemHalfWidth;
      $(this).animate({
         marginLeft: left
      },"slow",function(){
              $(this).css('position','static');
      });
  
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="resources_header">

    <h2>HEADER</h2>

  </div>
</div>
```